# Laravel - Call to undefined method App\Models\Core\VehicleModel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 api endpoint, I have two models:

- vehicle_models
- vehicle_makes

One vehicle make have many models:

```
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\VehicleMake;

class VehicleModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'vehicle_models';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                'id',
                'name',
                'make_id',
            ];

    public function vehiclemake()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(VehicleMake::class,'make_id','id');
    }

    public function getModelsByMake($id) {
        $vehiclemodels = DB::table('vehicle_models')->where('make_id',$id)->get();
        return $vehiclemodels;
    }
}
```

Then I have this Controller:

Controller

```
public function __construct(VehicleModel $myvehiclemodel)
{
  $this->myvehiclemodel = $myvehiclemodel;
}

public function getVehicleModelsByMake(Request $request, $id)
{
    try{
        $vehiclemodels =  $this->myvehiclemodel->getVehicleModelsByMake($id);
        return $this->success('Vehicle Model By Make Successfully Retrieved.', [
            'vehiclemodels'         => $vehiclemodels
        ]);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e);
        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::get('vehiclemodels/fetchbymake/{id}', 'VehicleModelController@getVehicleModelsByMake')->name('vehiclemodels.byMake');
```

I got this error:

> local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\Models\VehicleModel::getVehicleModelsByMake() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:50

How do I get it resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a typo, the method is called `getModelsByMake` instead of `getVehicleModelsByMake` in the `VehicleModel` class

Comment: Your answer is in the  laravel documents

Answer (score -2):

Use your controller in the `web.php` and change the route syntax

```
use App\Http\Controllers\VehicleModelController;
.
.
.

Route::get('vehiclemodels/fetchbymake/{id}', [VehicleModelController::class, 'getVehicleModelsByMake'])->name('vehiclemodels.byMake');
```

[read laravel 8 document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)